# how to put a div above a hover while it does not get removed

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a div above another div that has been hovered.
But when I get on the new div with my mouse, the hovered image disappeares..

Anyone know how to fix this?
The hover is in the tie by the way :)

My website is this: [My website](http://rdv-design.com/stageverslag2/home.html)

The code of the hover is this:

```
.vierkant img{
position:absolute;
width:116px;
height:254px;
top:0px;
margin:0 auto;
margin-left:-58px;
opacity:0.91;
z-index:3;

-webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;
-moz-transition-duration: 1.2s;
-o-transition-duration: 1.2s;
transition-duration: 1.2s;}

.vierkant img:hover{
position:absolute;
width:80%;
height:95%;
top:2%;
left:auto;
right:auto;
margin-left:-40%;
visibility:visible;
z-index:4;
opacity:1;}
```

and my html code is this:

```
<div class="vierkant" align="center">
    <img src="img/knoppen/vierkant.jpg" width="90" height="93" />         
</div>
```

Comment: I went to your website and everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: but the problem is, that I can't put text in the hovered picture of the tie. I mean, the hovered picture will disappear when I put my mouse on the text if I put text on the hovered picture

Comment: On just CSS I think you will not be able to do that. You'll have to write down some js to `show` the text you want after the hover transition finishes.

Comment: ah, that's to bad.. wished I could make my whole website only by using CSS ;) then  I do have to put some js in it I guess. anything you preffer that works on the same way? not that good in JS, still on my study!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know an answer has been accepted, but really? Using jQuery or javascript for such a simple task is way overkill when it can be done easily and **IS** generally done with CSS.

First off, the `align=""` property in html is deprecated. Also, why adding `top, left, margin, & margin-left` properties? It's pretty useless to redefine properties that aim to achieve the same thing (especially when some of them don't work because the `position` isn't relative).

Don't use images when you want to display text over it. Instead, use a div with `background-image: url('yourimg.png');`

I made a fiddle here with the correct code, removing any need for javascript, let alone jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/M4UYx/

Why is this solution way way better?

1. You don't need an image, if your background is just a color (as in your case)
2. You don't need javascript (and so it is more cross-browser)
3. You certainly don't need jQuery
4. You can position your text or w/e else without worrying about it disappearing on `:hover`

**EDIT:** Although not part of your original question; to center the position of your div, give it these properties:

```css
.vierkant {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0px -58px; /* -58px = width divided by 2 in negative */
}
```

Comment: everything is working so far! and I am pretty happy aswell that it works in css. There is just 1 problem.. I can't get it atop of the other image ( the tie ) and I can't lower it's opacity of the red square, else the hover will get a low opacity aswell. thanks so far!

Comment: got the transparency! just need it to get it on the right place ;)

Comment: I'll improve on this answer a bit later today if necessary, right now I have something urgent to do. And I don't see why you wouldn't get it atop the other img? It should naturally do so, unless your other img has a too high `z-index`? @DiederikEEn, true. I tested this on FF 14 (that's a pretty old version) and it flashes weirdly when the -moz-transition property is set, but it displays correctly when there's no transition. So simply removing the moz-transition is enough

Comment: no it's different, it's beneath everything somehow. the class: vierkant, is on top of everything. I will put it back online with the new square so you can see it when you have time thought! :)

Comment: it has no color atm, it's transparent. and if you scroll down it's in the middle when the line stops! link to my website again: http://rdv-design.com/stageverslag2/home.html

Comment: If you really don't want to put your text in the .square(vierkant) div (but I don't see why you wouldn't), it's not possible with css, and you'll have to use a js solution. But that depends, what is the goal ultimately? To display an orange mask over the text?

Comment: I do want to put text in the square, so that's all good now. I mean, it's working great so far! ;) The only thing missing is the right position of the square, on top of the tie.

Comment: @RyandeVries edited my answer, i hope it works now. If you want to ensure maximum Moz FF compatibility, don't forget to remove the `-moz-transition` line

Comment: not really no! it only get worse! hehe, the square on hover is even smaller then the square that´s transparent ;)

Comment: Sorry, but I tested this on your website with Google Chrome Inspector. It's got something to do with the rest of your page, not with this code. In effect, I don't know what's wrong, but it seems like your positions are pretty messed up all over the page. Please look into more information for positioning and margins, & post another question relating to this problem, as it doesn't really have anything to do with the original question, and the comments here are getting too long

Comment: As I figured out, you are totally right :) Already did something else before your awnser that made the square goes up, so I think everything is kinda messed up yes. Thanks for all the information and I will fix it right away!

Answer (score 0):

Look, I'll try to show you the logic behind it.

The `CSS` you already have, and there's no need to change it.

**The JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#HiddenObject").hide(); 
});

$(".vierkant").hover(
  function() {
    $("#HiddenObject").show('fast'); 
  }
  function() {
    $("#HiddenObject").hide('fast'); 
  }
);
```

Where `HiddenObject` is the object where you hold the text you want to show.

Take a look on [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zzLTL/)

Comment: your code gives an error on the 3rd function line, sorry, kinda a noob to this! :)

Comment: Have you included `jQuery API` to your project?

Comment: yes, deffinitally! Will try the newest awnser now where I only need to use CSS since that would be great! else, I will get back to you. thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that `#vierkant` is on the tie, and `#vierkant_info` is the div that appears when you click on that tie.

When you click on the `#vierkant` it wil slide in the div `#vierkant_info`

**Jquery**

```
 $("#vierkant").click(function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                $("#vierkant_info").slideDown("slow");

            });
```

**CSS**

```
#vierkant_info{
//your styling//
visibility:visible; // REMOVE THIS
display:none; //ADD THIS
z-index:4;
opacity:1;}
```

note: `<a href="#vierkant_info" id="vierkant">click</a></div>`

note I made div **ID** instead of **class**

Comment: Tried this, but nothing really happened anymore :S Will try the second awnser in hope that one will work!

Comment: are you sure you made `<a id="vierkant" href="#vierkant_info">Click me</a>` something like that

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to this

```
.vierkant div{
position:absolute;
background-color:;
height:254px;
width:116px;
top:0;
left:50%;
margin-left:-58px;
z-index:10;

-webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;
-moz-transition-duration: 1.2s;
-o-transition-duration: 1.2s;
transition-duration: 1.2s;}

.vierkant div:hover{
margin-left:0;
background-color:#FF6600;
height:90%;
width:90%;
top:5%;
left:5%;
z-index:10;}


.vierkant div.content{
opacity:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
top:0%;
left:0%;
overflow:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;}


.vierkant:hover div.content{
opacity:1;

-webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0s;
-o-transition-duration: 0s;
transition-duration: 0s;}
```

And it's Perfect now!

Thanks alot, since after seeing your code we finally got into this!